# Incircle of a region bounded by three smooth curves

Tags: geometry, circles, curves

Let $\gamma$ be a continuous Jordan curve comprised of three smooth pieces. Suppose that at the points that each two of the pieces meet, the tangent lines to the two pieces are different. Does there always exist a circle inside $\gamma$ that intersects each of the three pieces at exactly one point?

The answer is most likely no. Then what are some sufficient conditions on $\gamma$ that would guarantee such a circle exists?

Comment: Much more than sufficient condition you do need a necessary condition. Just drawing  figures you can exhibit several sufficient conditions.

Comment: Your problem could be extremely difficult maybe: It is not known as far an answer to an "analogue" problem for a square (every vertex of it in a general Jordan curve then containing the square).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the answer is most likely no? I would say, simply by thinking with Bolzano's theorem you could always find such a circle... I can't seem to visualize how pathological the curve could be in order to not being able to find a solution... excuse me if I'm being too rough here

Comment: Hi Astro, welcome. Jordan's conjecture currently a theorem went through many "proofs" that contained an error. With a smooth curve the thing is evident but the problem is that Jordan's curve definition is such that it does not prohibit many points in which there is no well-defined tangent (imagine an arc that contains many "teeth of saw").

Comment: Yes, sure, I know that, but since the statement of the question says that the three borders are smooth I couldn't help to comment... and thanks for the welcome words :)

Comment: @Astro, I don't see how Bolzano's theorem can be used here. What's the function?

Comment: Finding an expresion for the function would probably be difficult, but we can reason that since it is a Jordan curve it defines an inside bounded region, therefore it contains an infinitesimal circle which can be continuously enlarged until it contains the whole of the curve; then, by Bolzano, we can find a first point of contact with every one of the three side. Again, choose the first of the contact points of the enlarged circle with the curve, then start enlarging again until it meets the second side keeping track that it does not touch the first in more than one point

Comment: (if so, make a correction), repeat for the remaining side. Since all sides are smooth and the enlargement of the infinitesimal circle is continuous this operation can be performed.

Comment: @Astro: Concerning your "The answer is most likely no" take γ as a circle itself with chosen three points in it. I think this is a counterexample giving your "no" without "likely" . Am I wrong?

Comment: @Piquito, I was just thinking of that. I really need the three smooth pieces to make corners as they touch meaning the slopes are different at the corners.

Comment: @Astro, the process gets trickier when it goes from two to three points of contact. Enlarging the circle at that stage might cause it to intersect at more than one point.

Comment: @Piquito I don't think that counts in these hypotheses since a circle has not three sides (either zero or $\infty$)

Comment: @Marco I see what you mean, try this: define the family of all circles that have the property concerning two sides only (you have just proven it is non-empty), if you get close enough to their intersection point the circles shall be very small. If you go too far away from there it will be too large cutting, hence, the third side. Apply Bolzano again to find the first point of contact to get your desired circle. (Be careful here, you might have to justify continuity of the family, which is not the same as continuity over the contact points).

Comment: @Astro: Three distinct points in a circle determine three of your  "sides" of the Jordan curve defined by the circle itself. Regards.

Comment: @Piquito If you allow that, then, any set of isolated points would be a Jordan curve. Which does not hold. Marco's hypotheses says **three** sides, not **at least three** sides. Regards to you too :)

Comment: What you say is completely absurde, dear friend. What I wanted to say is that your Jordan curve at the beginning is a circle. How you could find  another circle satisfying your requirements?

Comment: That is totally fine, what I am saying is that it is not what is stated for this particular question

Comment: All right, Astro. Regards.